# Rotate a window or another program?

Tags: windows-7, windows, gui, rotate

I would like to know if there is a way for me to rotate a windowed program running on Windows?

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: The example image (http://i.stack.imgur.com/3vO8A.png) is not rotated, it is mirrored. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: ah yes, you are correct (edited op post) :) what i want is rotated :) 
like this http://oi41.tinypic.com/w1pxqa.jpg